# How to cover the whole screen background with 1 image using boostrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My Personal Website</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="webpage.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="jumbotron">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

webpage.css

```
.jumbotron{
  position:relative;
  background: #000 url(background.jpg) center center;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-size:cover;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

When I use the following pieces of code, there is some white space at the top and bottom and  a ">" at the top-left corner in the white space. Please tell me how to solve the problem. It is my first time to use bootstrap.Thank you.

Comment: Show us what it looks like

Comment: `>` at the top-left corner, it's just typo error, you need to check your HTML for extra `>` defiantly in Head section.

Comment: The > is gone but the background image still cannot file the whole page ! Thank you

Comment: [John](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4264357/john-louie-dela-cruz)      link: http://ec2-52-76-96-165.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com/

Comment: [Shehary](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4258081/shehary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have bottom margin after nav here

```
.navbar {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 20px; <----Here
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

And margins to `jumbotron` selector

```
.jumbotron {
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px; <---Here
    color: inherit;
    background-color: #EEE;
}
```

causing the issue, change margin to `0px;` better use custom selectors and override the margin with 0px;

Comment: [Shehary](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4258081/shehary) - Thank you. How did you find out this information.

Comment: browser console log, right click on an element and `inspect element` it will open browser console log and you can see what's going on behind the scene, HTML, JS and CSS